# Combinatorics: Number of ways to select w out s points on a circle with at least one point in between

Tags: combinatorics

If I arrange $s$ points in a circle and want to choose $w$ points of them, there are clearly $\binom{s}{w}$ possibilities. However, now I would like to choose those points to have at least one (not chosen) point in between. For the first point, there are $s$ possibilities, for the second $s-2$, but for the third the number of possibilities appear to depend on where I have chosen the first two (i.e., if they had exactly one point in between, the third point has $s-3$ choices, while otherwise there would be $s-4$).

Is there a standard way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, I can suggest a reformulation of this problem which can help you visualise it better: Consider an s-sided regular polygon. Now you need to find the number of polygons (not necessarily regular) with w (<s) sides such that the w-sided polygon does not share any of its sides with the s-sided polygon.

Comment: What does it mean to have $w$ points with one point "in between"? "Between" usually means between two points. Do you mean a subset $W \subsetneq S$ that for any two adjacent points of $W$ there is at least one point of $S \backslash W$ on the arc between them?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Sorry for not being clear. One could rephrase the question as coloring w points out of s points, such that no two adjacent points are colored.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a "standard" way for solving such a problem, there is a well known  paper by [Konstantinos Drakakis](http://facta.junis.ni.ac.rs/mai/mai221/f221-01.pdf), see the portion "A slight variant" You could go through that, or here is a method I use.

- Form *w* blocks of chosen not chosen, $\boxed{C N}$
- $(s-2w)$ "singles" now remain in a total of $(s-w)$ *entities*
- Place the blocks among the entities in $\Large\binom{s-w}{w}$ ways
- But by forming blocks, the circle "contracts", and the blocks are getting only $(s-w)$ starting points instead $s$ choices, so multiply by $\Large\frac{s}{s-w}$
- Final answer $\Large\frac{s}{s-w}\binom{s-w}{w}$